# jQuery load a div wrapper before a div after page load

Tags: jquery, html-parsing, append, jquery-load

I want to a load a div to wrap around another div after page load and have CSS applied to that div.

This is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use jQuery that once the page is loaded to add a div wrapper around the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body2" style="xyx"><div id="body">

    </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a lot PHP, JavaScript and content between the body already and this is the solution I need for a quick fix. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wrap` method:

```
$(function(){
    $('#body').wrap('<div id="body2" class="class"/>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it,

```
$('#body').wrap('<div id="body2" />');
```

> The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be
>   passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This
>   structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only
>   one inmost element. A copy of this structure will be wrapped around
>   each of the elements in the set of matched elements. This method
>   returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

[***Read more***](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).